# Sum Of 2 Convex is affine. Prove 2 functions are affine

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis

Let here be two convex functions:
$f(x)$ and $g(x)$
let there be two real numbers:
$a$ and $b$
so it is known that:
$f(x) + g(x) = ax + b$

Prove that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both affine

*meaning that there are $a_f$,$b_f$,$a_g$,$b_g$, so that:

$f(x) = a_fx+b_f$

$g(x) = a_gx+b_g$

** This has something to do with the fact that a function is both convex and concave IFF it is affine(had to prove it just now)

Comment: Hint : Use that if $g$ is convex then $-g$ is concave.

Comment: If the sum of two functions is concave, then at least one of the two is also concave. That shouldn't be too hard to prove, I think.

Comment: I don't quiet understand how it helps me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider two real numbers $x$ and $y$, and $\lambda\in[0,1]$ then
$$\eqalign{
I_1&=\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda) f(y)-f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)\geq0\cr
I_2&=\lambda g(x)+(1-\lambda) g(y)-g(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)\geq0
}
$$
But
$$
I_1+I_2=\lambda(ax+b)+(1-\lambda)(ay+b)-a(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)-b=0
$$
So, we must have $I_1=I_2=0$ that is, for all $(x,y)$ and $\lambda\in[0,1]$ we have
$$\eqalign{f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)&= 
\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda) f(y)\cr
g(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)&= 
\lambda g(x)+(1-\lambda) g(y)
}
$$
This means that both $f$ and $g$ are affine functions.